# Dynamically call async method

Tags: c#, linq-expressions, c#-9.0

I need to write tests to verify that multiple ASP.NET Core routes download an excel spreadsheet.  So I have this so far:

```cs
private async Task VerifyExcelIsDownloaded(Expression<Action<IReportRepository>> repoCall)
{
    // Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IReportRepository>();
    mock.Setup(repoCall);

    var controller = new ReportController(mock.Object);

    // Act
    var result = await controller.GetBadgeReadersDownloadAsync();
            
    // Assert
    Assert.IsType<FileStreamResult>(result);

    var file = result as FileStreamResult;
    Assert.Equal("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", file.ContentType);
}
```

The repository call I've got taken care of via the expression parameter, but for the "act" part, I don't know how to replace the `GetBadgeReadersDownloadAsync`.  I need that method call to be able to be passed into the help method as well.

Ideally I'd end up then having multiple tests like this:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetBadgeReadersDownloadAsync_DownloadsExcel()
{
    Expression<Action<IReportRepository>> repoCall = x => x.GetBadgeReadersForBarcodesAsync();
    var controllerMethod = nameof(ReportController.GetBadgeReadersDownloadAsync);

    await VerifyExcelIsDownloaded(repoCall, controllerMethod);         
}
```

Comment: Func that takes a controller and returns a task?

Comment: No, because the helper method is the one that creates the controller.

Comment: If `Func<Controller, Task>` does not work I really see no good options... You could go with virtual methods and "template method" pattern... but that's even farther away from expressions...

Comment: @Gargoyle: I don't see any reason why `Func<Controller, Task>` wouldn't work. The helper method creates the controller and then passes it to the delegate.

Comment: @StephenCleary Thanks, that helped.  It's exactly what Wiktor told me to do but it didn't click until I saw the signature.  Thanks guys!

Comment: @WiktorZychla If you want to mark that as the answer I'll be happy to click it.  I ended up using `Func<ReportController, Task<ActionResult>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer accepted by the Original Poster (in the comments below the question) is to use a function that takes a controller and returns a task and pass this function alongside the expression to the testing method:

```
public async Task Verify...( Expression... repoCall, Func<Controller, Task<ActionResult>> actFunc )
```

The testing method creates a controller and passes it to this function that does the actual job here.